# Pass data from edittext in dialog to adapter android

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I created an `EditText` which will display as dialog on click on an item in `GridView`. My basic purpose is user can click on a day to add events and the event details will appear on the calendar.

This is my code :

```
calendarview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int pos,
                long id) {


            tvEvent = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvEvent) ;

                Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalendarViews.this);
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setTitle("Enter the event details");
                edEvent = new EditText(CalendarViews.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tbLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                edEvent.setLayoutParams(tbLayout);
                builder.setView(edEvent);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Set",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        eventDetails = edEvent.getText().toString();

                        String event[]= new String[34];

                        tvEvent.setText(event[pos]); //if pos = 5 , then text added to 5 position of all months

                    }
                });
```

How to avoid the text getting added to all the months?

Comment: can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add/modify the list passed to the adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to notify it from change. This is possible only if you have access to the list from the dialog shown.
Beware of concurrency.